# Workday Function to add Workdays

Tags: vba, excel, function

I'm trying to run code based off of dates in the D column. The code below works. But the "if" part of the conditional formatting needs to be + 30 workdays, not plus thirty days. I'm assuming that the WORKDAY function helps with this. But when I try + workday(30) and things like that, I don't get anywhere.

```
For Each oKey In oDictionary.keys
    Editing_Sheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter Field:=1,    Criteria1:=CStr(oKey)
    LastRowFiltered = Editing_Sheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        If Range("D" & LastRowFiltered) <= Date + 30 Then
         'run code'
```

Comment: Also my VBA isn't recognizing anything at all with the workday function

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To use the worksheet *Workday()* function within **VBA:**

```
Sub WhyWork()
    Dim d1 As Date, wf As WorksheetFunction
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    d2 = wf.WorkDay(Date, 30)
    MsgBox Date & vbCrLf & d2
End Sub
```

Comment: `Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction` is genius. Don't know why I never thought of that!

Comment: @guitarthrower  I must admit that I am a bit lazy.

Comment: It's not lazy. It's...efficient! (that's what I keep telling myself at least)

Comment: The Sub name is pretty awesome too

Answer (score 1):

To build on @Gary's Student's answer, here's an example written as a VBA function, returning the calculated date. So, if you want to feed it a date and get one back, or need to loop through an array or range of cells, might be useful.

```
'Workday Function via VBA
Function WorkDayCalc(ByVal d1 As Date, ByVal days As Integer) As Date
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    WorkDayCalc = wf.WorkDay(d1, days)
End Function

'Example Usage
Sub Test_WorkDayCalc()
    Dim d As Date, i As Integer
    d = CDate("01/03/2022")
    i = 30
    MsgBox "Start " + CStr(d) & vbCrLf & "End  " + CStr(WorkDayCalc(d, i))
End Sub
```